# Problem declaring Global Variable in C++

Tags: c++, cplex

I have a global variable in the class:

```
IloModel model;
```

that is going to be shared amongst several functions of the class.

In one of the functions, I am going to initialize this model like:

```
model(env);
```

I get the error:
Error      1              error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

This works if I write in the function:

```
IEnv env;
IloModel model(env);
```

but not if the model object is declared globally.

**Please advice how to make model object global so same object can be shared amongst several functions?**

Comment: "global variable in the class" is a misnomer. From the description, "that is going to be shared amongst several functions of the class," it sounds like a plain class variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you do

```
IloModel model;
```

It is being initialised with the default constructor; so `IloModel()`

What you need to do is

```
model = IloModel(env);
```

There error is probably because it is looking for a function model with one paramatere and not finding one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you mean with "global" because it seems you're talking about a member of the class. Anyway if your data is copyable you can do

```
model = IloModel(env);
```

this will create a new model and copy it over the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare env globally also and then directly initialize model with env?
In other words, put this globally:

```
IEnv env;
IloModel model(env);
```

Otherwise, you cannot call the constructor to initialize model, you need another init method on `IloModel` class to specify the `IEnv` after the construction.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call the constructor of `model` of object at a later point of time. You need to do it at the time of definition of the object itself. If `env` is also global then you can do `IModel model(env)`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are calling on the model class, is it's constructor.  As a member of your class (global to the class, but certainly not the application unless it is static and accessible), you get to construct it *once* and that is in the initializer-list of the class that has it, e.g:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    IloModel model;

public:
     MyClass(IEnv _env) : model(_env) // constructs model here, passing env
     {
     };

     void someFunction()
     {
         // use model here
     };
}; // eo class MyClass
```

Now, I do not know what `IEnv` is at all (or the model for that matter) so this might not work for you if the logic dictates that you need to construct model with a different `IEnv` each time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your last example, you call the constructor, a special function to initialize the object. The first example tries to call the `operator()` on your object `model`, and if the class `IloModel` does not define one, it doesn't exist.

You could, however, call `IloModel(env);` which would create an temporary object and immediately destroy it again, heh.